# How to enable cross-origin in spring -boot for micro-services

Tags: spring-boot, cors, api-gateway

I have nearly 5 spring boot applications which are connected to discovery service to communicate with each other. and also I want to expose some controllers to the public, so how can I enable cross-origin? should I do it in all controller level or from discovery? Any other suggestion Please!

Comment: It really depends.  Sometimes instead of exposing many controllers (services) to the public, one might create a facade service to "front" the other services, and/or put the services behind an API gateway or some other security mechanism.   Then we only need to enable cross-origin access to the facade service (or at the API gateway) but not at the individual microservice level.

Comment: @peekay can I use kong API getaway in front of all services to handle cors?

Comment: Yes there's a plugin: https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/  (see limitations at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`@CrossOrigin`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) annotation either on your controller classes or on each of your controller methods that you want to permit.

You can also create a [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) Bean in one of your configuration classes where you can establish cross origin configuration at a global level.

Edit: I like @peekay suggestion as well.

Comment: can I use kong API getaway in front of all services to handle cors?

Comment: I don't see why not. You would just have to enable CORS between your APIs and the Kong API gateway. Then allow Kong to proxy all of the API requests to your back-end APIs.

Comment: There's no need to enable CORS between the microservice APIs and Kong in this case... simply let Kong handle CORS between the gateway and the browser. (Kong [has a plugin for this purpose](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/)). The microservices don't need to know about CORS at all (and arguably, nor should they -- they should be client agnostic.) .

Answer (score 0):

I have used Kong Api Gateway in front of all services. To enable cross origin.its very easy to do it in single place rather than in every single controller